# How to draw a heat map for some data across a circular region?

Tags: plotting

I have the following data over a circular region like this:
[image]

How can I make a heat map across the circular area?

Comment: Please post the data.

Comment: Maybe try 'ListContourPlot' or 'ListDensityPlot'?

Answer (score 5):

Here's your data.  You can fill in the empty spaces, where values are zero, using your own method.

```
data = {{0, 0, 0, 487.9, 0, 503.9, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 471.7, 0, 462.7, 
0, 501.2, 0, 0}, {0, 486.3, 0, 441.8, 0, 442.3, 0, 510.7, 0}, {0, 
0, 437.1, 0, 409.8, 0, 450.2, 0, 0}, {0, 453.7, 0, 412.3, 0, 
394.5, 0, 478.2, 0}, {471.1, 0, 418.4, 0, 396.5, 0, 403.0, 0, 
484.7}, {0, 437.7, 0, 407.0, 0, 380.7, 0, 444.2, 0}, {476.5, 0, 
411.7, 0, 0, 0, 391.8, 0, 477.7}, {0, 438.4, 0, 420.8, 0, 388.9, 
0, 440.4, 0}, {476.3, 0, 428.6, 0, 408.6, 0, 411.5, 0, 490.8}, {0,
 465.6, 0, 435.5, 0, 399.2, 0, 462.6, 0}, {0, 0, 455.9, 0, 414.8, 
0, 444.8, 0, 0}, {0, 513.7, 0, 429.3, 0, 444.7, 0, 495.0, 0}, {0, 
0, 495.8, 0, 447.2, 0, 529.0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 488.3, 0, 558.8, 0,
 0, 0}};

MatrixPlot[data, Mesh -> True, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
FrameTicks -> None, MeshStyle -> Thin, 
FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0], PlotRangePadding -> 0.0, 
AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: MatrixPlot]

Comment: this is great! Can you please suggest a method to interpolate?

Comment: Why not fill empty cells with the averages of the closest cells?

Comment: How can I set the plotrange and display the legend?

Comment: Try "PlotLegends -> Automatic"